# make my zsh prompt show mode in vi mode

Tags: shell, prompt, zsh

I use `bindkey -v` (for bash-ers `set -o vi` I think that works in zsh too) or vi(m) mode. but it bugs me that I don't have any visual cue to tell me whether I'm in insert mode or command mode. Does anyone know how I can make my prompt display the mode?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found [this](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/zlewidgets) via [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/151803/how-do-i-customize-zshs-vim-mode). Here's the basic example, though I'm still customizing it for myself:

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    RPS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/-- NORMAL --}/(main|viins)/-- INSERT --}"
    RPS2=$RPS1
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

I'd explain it except I don't really understand it yet

Comment: I tried this approach but found one issue. If you do something like `CTRL+C` while in vi-command mode, the prompt will reset, but indicate youre in command mode when youre really in insert mode. `zle-line-init` should always change the indicator to insert mode. For some reason `$KEYMAP` is not updated properly when zle-line-init is called.

Comment: `zle reset-prompt` will delete 1 (or more) lines above the prompt (if your prompt is multiline) when redrawing :( This is a showstopper for me.

Comment: @PawełGościcki it seems to be an issue when you have two or more lines of PS1.

Comment: @Metaphox I know, that why I've said "(if your prompt is multiline)". Any fix for that?

Comment: @PawełGościcki aww sorry i somehow skipped the words in parentheses , bad habit. No, I didn't find a fix for that. What platform are you on? Was wondering if this is OS X specific.

Comment: I believe it's ZSH specific. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: this post has a good explanation (though the code from the article doesn't work) https://dougblack.io/words/zsh-vi-mode.html

Answer (score 20):

You've already found `zle-keymap-select` which is executed whenever the mode changes. You could use it to set some other visual indicator than the prompt, depending on what your terminal supports it (and your taste in mode indicator display, of course).

There is a standard [terminfo capability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/is-it-possible-to-display-stuff-below-the-prompt-at-a-prompt/1029#1029) to change the shape of the cursor. However some terminals display the same cursor in both modes. Xterm's notion of a less visible cursor is to make it blink (and this must be enabled with the `-bc` command line argument or `cursorBlink` resource).

```
zle-keymap-select () {
  case $KEYMAP in
    vicmd) print -rn -- $terminfo[cvvis];; # block cursor
    viins|main) print -rn -- $terminfo[cnorm];; # less visible cursor
  esac
}
```

With some terminals, you can also change the cursor color with `print -n '\e]12;pink\a'` (by color name) or `print -n '\e]12;#abcdef\a'` (by RGB specification). These sequences are described in the xterm documentation, in the [`ctlseqs`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) file; modern terminal emulators typically emulate xterm, though they might not support all its features.

Comment: For some reason I get `main` for `KEYMAP` instead of `viins`, not sure why.

Comment: @Graeme `main` is an alias for `viins` or `emacs` depending on whether [zsh thought](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) your favorite editor was vi or not when it started. I thought it would use `viins` when switching the mode back from `vicmd`, but it seems that it uses `main` instead. Updated.

Comment: You still need to double up with `zle-line-init` (or whatever alternative) since `zle-keymap-select` does not get called if hitting enter changes the keymap.

Answer (score 10):

For the people having problems using reset-prompt with multiline prompts, in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622943/zsh-vi-mode-status-line I ended up doing:

```
terminfo_down_sc=$terminfo[cud1]$terminfo[cuu1]$terminfo[sc]$terminfo[cud1]

function insert-mode () { echo "-- INSERT --" }
function normal-mode () { echo "-- NORMAL --" }

precmd () {
    # yes, I actually like to have a new line, then some stuff and then 
    # the input line
    print -rP "
[%D{%a, %d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S}] %n %{$fg[blue]%}%m%{$reset_color%}"

    # this is required for initial prompt and a problem I had with Ctrl+C or
    # Enter when in normal mode (a new line would come up in insert mode,
    # but normal mode would be indicated)
    PS1="%{$terminfo_down_sc$(insert-mode)$terminfo[rc]%}%~ $ "
}
function set-prompt () {
    case ${KEYMAP} in
      (vicmd)      VI_MODE="$(normal-mode)" ;;
      (main|viins) VI_MODE="$(insert-mode)" ;;
      (*)          VI_MODE="$(insert-mode)" ;;
    esac
    PS1="%{$terminfo_down_sc$VI_MODE$terminfo[rc]%}%~ $ "
}

function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    set-prompt
    zle reset-prompt
}
preexec () { print -rn -- $terminfo[el]; }

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

Answer (score 9):

Another solution for changing the cursor shape between I-beam and block (for underscore, use `\033[4 q`). Add this to your `~/.zshrc`.

```
zle-keymap-select () {
if [ $KEYMAP = vicmd ]; then
    printf "\033[2 q"
else
    printf "\033[6 q"
fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle-line-init () {
zle -K viins
printf "\033[6 q"
}
zle -N zle-line-init
bindkey -v
```

Modified from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95078. Tested in gnome-terminal 3.22.

---

### Update

Yet another solution to changing the cursor shapes [can be found here](https://emily.st/2013/05/03/zsh-vi-cursor/). This one apparently works for iTerm2, which I don't have the means to test, but adding it in here in case it is useful for someone else. The final addition to your `~/.zshrc` would be

```
function zle-keymap-select zle-line-init
{
    # change cursor shape in iTerm2
    case $KEYMAP in
        vicmd)      print -n -- "\E]50;CursorShape=0\C-G";;  # block cursor
        viins|main) print -n -- "\E]50;CursorShape=1\C-G";;  # line cursor
    esac

    zle reset-prompt
    zle -R
}

function zle-line-finish
{
    print -n -- "\E]50;CursorShape=0\C-G"  # block cursor
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-line-finish
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

Comment: I confirmed that the updated script for iTerm2 indeed worked.

Comment: The first script will only work on terminals and terminal emulators that understand DECSCUSR.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution that doesn't clutter up my shell

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use to change the cursor between 'Block' and 'Beam' shape in zsh:

*(Tested with **Termite**, **gnome-terminal** and **mate-terminal**)*

```
# vim mode config
# ---------------

# Activate vim mode.
bindkey -v

# Remove mode switching delay.
KEYTIMEOUT=5

# Change cursor shape for different vi modes.
function zle-keymap-select {
  if [[ ${KEYMAP} == vicmd ]] ||
     [[ $1 = 'block' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[1 q'

  elif [[ ${KEYMAP} == main ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} == viins ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} = '' ]] ||
       [[ $1 = 'beam' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[5 q'
  fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select

# Use beam shape cursor on startup.
echo -ne '\e[5 q'

# Use beam shape cursor for each new prompt.
preexec() {
   echo -ne '\e[5 q'
}
```

Comment: This will only work on terminals and terminal emulators that understand DECSCUSR.

Comment: I like this.  I worry that writing to preexec might interact with other usages, so I modified it slightly to use `add-zsh-hook` like so: https://gist.github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/8ba56e957c861719691105e52592ee62

Comment: It does not work everywhere. Let's say in intellij idea it "eats" characters after mode switching.

Comment: Confirmed to work in kitty and also within tmux via kitty.

Answer (score 6):

you can try [VimMode](http://martin.krischik.com/index.php/Z-Shell/VimMode)

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit less linkish and a bit more explanatory. I like to know how things work.

Comment: Actually it is all there. Look at the comments the functions and how they are bound to the mode change events.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using Zsh with [Bullet Train](https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train.zsh) theme. Following the example given by [Sebastian Blask's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163645), I ended up with the code bellow

```
bindkey -v
KEYTIMEOUT=1

function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    case ${KEYMAP} in
        (vicmd)      BULLETTRAIN_PROMPT_CHAR="N" ;;
        (main|viins) BULLETTRAIN_PROMPT_CHAR="I" ;;
        (*)          BULLETTRAIN_PROMPT_CHAR="I" ;;
    esac
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

This will only change de default **$** to the letters **N** to normal mode and **I** to insert mode.

This image is an example when in normal mode I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another version, based from [Sebastian Blask's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163645/227009).
This was intended to be as non-intrusive as possible, as all the other solutions I could find used extra lines, status on the right, or added characters.

This simply changes the color of `$` from white to red when normal mode is enabled. Edit the prompt to your liking

```
bindkey -v
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    case ${KEYMAP} in
        (vicmd)      PROMPT=$'%{\e[0;32m%}%~%{\e[0m%} %{\e[0;31m%}$%{\e[0m%} ' ;;
        (main|viins) PROMPT=$'%{\e[0;32m%}%~%{\e[0m%} $ ' ;;
        (*)          PROMPT=$'%{\e[0;32m%}%~%{\e[0m%} $ ' ;;
    esac
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

Answer (score 2):

## A version for `oh-my-zsh` users

There's a plugin for `oh-my-zsh` called `vi-mode` that can be found here:

[robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/vi-mode](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode)

I use Antigen to manage my plugins, so including it was as simple as adding this to my `.zshrc`:

```
antigen bundle vi-mode
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in your `.zshrc` to change the cursor based on the mode you're in. It's taken from here: https://gist.github.com/LukeSmithxyz/e62f26e55ea8b0ed41a65912fbebbe52

```bsh
# vi mode
bindkey -v
export KEYTIMEOUT=1

# Change cursor shape for different vi modes.
function zle-keymap-select {
  if [[ ${KEYMAP} == vicmd ]] ||
     [[ $1 = 'block' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[1 q'
  elif [[ ${KEYMAP} == main ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} == viins ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} = '' ]] ||
       [[ $1 = 'beam' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[5 q'
  fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle-line-init() {
    zle -K viins # initiate `vi insert` as keymap (can be removed if `bindkey -V` has been set elsewhere)
    echo -ne "\e[5 q"
}
zle -N zle-line-init
echo -ne '\e[5 q' # Use beam shape cursor on startup.
preexec() { echo -ne '\e[5 q' ;} # Use beam shape cursor for each new prompt.
```

You can customise the type of cursor you want (blinking or not, |, rectangle or _) by changing the numbers in the following sequences \e[5 q (5 is for beam, 1 is for block) as follows:

```
Set cursor style (DECSCUSR), VT520.
0  ⇒  blinking block.
1  ⇒  blinking block (default).
2  ⇒  steady block.
3  ⇒  blinking underline.
4  ⇒  steady underline.
5  ⇒  blinking bar, xterm.
6  ⇒  steady bar, xterm.
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, I can understand your concern and if you don't mind using a plugin, **I think this one I wrote can help you show the vi mode status perfectly, also the additional bonus of better experience on vi mode and so on**.

**zsh-vi-mode**: A better and friendly vi(vim) mode plugin for ZSH.
https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode

This plugin has provided a `ZVM_MODE` variable for you to retrieve current vi mode and better show the indicator.

And currently the below modes are supported:

```bsh
ZVM_MODE_NORMAL
ZVM_MODE_INSERT
ZVM_MODE_VISUAL
ZVM_MODE_VISUAL_LINE
ZVM_MODE_REPLACE
```

For updating the vi mode indicator, we should add our commands to `zvm_after_select_vi_mode_commands`. For example:

After you install this plugin

```bsh
# The plugin will auto execute this `zvm_after_select_vi_mode` function
function zvm_after_select_vi_mode() {
  case $ZVM_MODE in
    $ZVM_MODE_NORMAL)
      # Something you want to do...
      ;;
    $ZVM_MODE_INSERT)
      # Something you want to do...
      ;;
    $ZVM_MODE_VISUAL)
      # Something you want to do...
      ;;
    $ZVM_MODE_VISUAL_LINE)
      # Something you want to do...
      ;;
    $ZVM_MODE_REPLACE)
      # Something you want to do...
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Here is an example:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

The [zsh-vim-mode](https://github.com/softmoth/zsh-vim-mode) plugin is able to show an indicator for insert, command, search, replace, and visual modes. It uses the basic technique of other answers to hook in to the various ZLE hooks (zle-keymap-select, zle-isearch-update, etc.). It checks `[[ $ZLE_STATE = *overwrite* ]]` for replace mode. It checks `$REGION_ACTIVE` to identify visual mode.

The logic is complicated by some quirks of how ZSH fires events when leaving isearch mode.

Another nice feature of the module is the ability to change the cursor shape and color based on the mode. For example, you can use a vertical bar in INSERT mode and a blinking underline in SEARCH mode.

Comment: This plugin is great.