# Display stuff below the prompt at a shell prompt?

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt

Lets's say my prompt looks like this (the _ represents my cursor)

```
~ % _
```

Is there any way I could make it look like this

```
~ % _
[some status]
```

<sub>*The question was originally about zsh, but now has other answers.*</sub>

Comment: How about screen + buobu?: https://launchpad.net/byobu, and maybe http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/byobu-a-shortcut-to-a-prettier-screen/ for screenshots

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following settings seem to work. The text on the second line disappears if the command line overflows the first line. The `preexec` function erases the second line before running the command; if you want to keep it, change to `preexec () { echo; }`.

```
terminfo_down_sc=$terminfo[cud1]$terminfo[cuu1]$terminfo[sc]$terminfo[cud1]
PS1_2='[some status]'
PS1="%{$terminfo_down_sc$PS1_2$terminfo[rc]%}%~ %# "
preexec () { print -rn -- $terminfo[el]; }
```

`%` escapes are documented in the zsh manual (`man zshmisc`).

Terminfo is a terminal access API. Zsh has a `terminfo` module that gives access to the terminal description database: `$terminfo[$cap]` is the sequence of characters to send to exercise the terminal's capability `$cap`, i.e., to run its `$cap` command. See `man 5 terminfo` (on Linux, the section number may vary on other unices) for more information.

The sequence of actions is: move the cursor down one line (`cud1`), then back up (`cuu1`); save the cursor position (`sc`); move the cursor down one line; print `[some status]`; restore the cursor position. The down-and-up bit at the beginning is only necessary in case the prompt is on the bottom line of the screen. The preexec line erases the second line (`el`) so that it doesn't get mixed up with output from the command.

If the text on the second line is wider than the terminal, the display may be garbled. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in a pinch to repair.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `bash` equivalent of Gilles' zsh solution.  Bash doesn't have a native terminfo module, but the `tput` command (bundled with `terminfo`) does much the same thing.

```
PS1_line1='\w \$ '
PS1_line2='[some status]'

if (tput cuu1 && tput sc && tput rc && tput el) >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    PS1="
\[$(tput cuu1; tput sc)\]
\[${PS1_line2}$(tput rc)\]${PS1_line1}"
    PS2="\[$(tput el)\]> "
    trap 'tput el' DEBUG
else
    PS1="$PS1_line2 :: $PS1_line1"
fi
```

If the terminal doesn't support one of the capabilities, it will fall back to a one-line prompt.

The `trap` line is a hacky way to emulate zsh's `preexec` function.  See https://superuser.com/questions/175799/ for more info.

**EDIT**: Improved script based on Gilles' comments.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for the input!  I think I've got it working better now.  Tried bash 4.1.5 in gnome-terminal and xterm, and bash 3.2.48 in OSX Terminal.