# vi mode doesn't display correctly on new term

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt, termcap

This is a continuation of [my](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547/make-my-zsh-prompt-show-mode-in-vi-mode) [previous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/is-it-possible-to-display-stuff-below-the-prompt-at-a-prompt) questions. I currently have the following in `~/.zsh.d/functions.sh`

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    psvar[1]="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/}/(main|viins)/-- INSERT --}"
    zle reset-prompt
}
precmd() {
    psvar[2]=()
    vcs_info
    [[ -n $vcs_info_msg_0_ ]] && psvar[2]="$vcs_info_msg_0_"
}
```

and relevant sections from my `~/.zshrc`

```
if [ -d ~/.zsh.d ]; then
    for i in ~/.zsh.d/*; do
        if [ -r $i ]; then
            source $i
        fi
    done
    unset i
fi

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
autoload -Uz colors && colors
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats '[%b]'
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' branchformats '[%b|%r]'
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' actionformats '[%b|%a]'

# 063 is a blue

# vimode implentation
psvar[1]='-- INSERT --'
local down=$terminfo[cud1]$terminfo[cuu1]$terminfo[sc]$terminfo[cud1]
local mode="%F{063}%1 %(1v.%1v.)%f"
local up=$terminfo[rc]
local vimode=$down$mode$up

# current working directory as blue
local cwd='%F{063}%1~%f'

# display git branch if git repo
local git='%(2v.%F{099}%2v%f.)'

# if root then red # else blue %
local prompt_char='%(!.%F{red}%#%f.%F{063}%#%f)'

PS1=$'%{$vimode%} $cwd $git $prompt_char '
RPS1='%m'
preexec () { print -rn -- $terminfo[el]; }
```

This works right, except that it doesn't display `-- INSERT --` when the shell is first started, after that it works as expected.

*Other improvement suggestions welcome.*

**Update** I decided to work around the issue, though I still don't know why it works. For now I've set `psvar[1]` to `-- INSERT --` out of the box, since I know it will be insert on start. This doesn't feel like a proper resolution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my hacker it appears I fixed it by setting

```
psvar[1]='-- INSERT --'
```

before doing anything else with my vimode... I"m not sure I'm 100% satisfied with my solution, but it functions.